# angularjs module not loading for me

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am stuck on trying to get rid of the following error:

> Error: $injector:modulerr   Module Error Failed to instantiate module
>   ptoApp due to: Error: [$injector:unpr]

Here is my app.js code:

```
angular.module('ptoApp', ['ui.router','ngResource'])
    .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider

    // route for the home page
    .state('app', {
        url:'dist',
        views: {
            'header': {
                templateUrl : 'views/header.html'
            }
        }
    });
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
});
```

Here is my html body:

```
<body>
        <div id="container">
            <div class="header" ui-view="header"></div>
            <div class="info" ui-view="info"></div>
            <div class="body" ui-view="body"></div>
            <div class="secondBody" ui-view="secondBody"></div>
        </div>
        <!-- build:js scripts/main.js -->
        <script src="../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/angular-ui/build/angular-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app.min.js"></script>
        <!-- endbuild -->
    </body>
```

I keep getting the following error, but all of my js files to bower seem to be loading. I am not sure if I am missing something I should be loading. I am also using browser-sync and I am not sure if that is throwing something off too. All of the js files seem to be loading into the index.html file fine.

Comment: Don't load the minified version (`angular.min.js`), instead load `angular.js` and you'll be able to see more detailed error

Comment: Now it is saying
Error: $injector:unpr
Unknown Provider
Unknown provider: e
This error results from the $injector being unable to resolve a required dependency. To fix this, make sure the dependency is defined and spelled correctly

Comment: Maybe some of the JS return 404 error?

Comment: no 404, but I am getting 304 not modified statuses for my js files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have minified your `app.min.js`, but the original `app.js` **is not** minification safe.

Your `.config` line is injecting dependencies, but does not have a static method for locating those dependencies.  when minified, `.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {` will be turned into something similar to `.config(function(e, f) {`, and the original identity of the dependencies is lost.

There are two ways to resolve this issue, according to the [angular documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#!):

1)  Provide an inline array of the string names of the dependencies to be referenced.

```
.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', 
        function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {...}])
```

2)  Use the `$inject` property.

```
var configFunction = function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){...};
configFunction.$inject = ['$stateProvider','$urlRouterProvider'];

angular.module('ptoApp', ['ui.router','ngResource'])
.config(configFunction);
```

The choice of which to use is mostly a matter of preference and coding style;  The inline method is much more commonly used in most examples.

Comment: ah that makes a lot of sense. Thanks. I will go down this path.

Comment: yeah, that fixed all the run time errors, now I am not getting my ui-view to load.

Comment: if I had to guess, that is because you only have one route on the `dist` path, but you probably aren't trying to load `http://yoursite.com/dist`

Comment: Got my views to load, yay, all set. Thanks.